# save brushed points in Shiny in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have a code as follows and I want to add a `Save` button to points that are brushed. Many thanks in advance.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", brush = "plot_brush"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  x <- NULL
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
  })
  output$info <- renderPrint({
    x <<- brushedPoints(mtcars, input$plot_brush, xvar = "wt", yvar = "mpg")
    x
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: On click of the save button do you want the brushed rows saved as dataframe in your environment Or you want to write them as csv?

Comment: hello, exporting them as csv would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `actionButton` when clicked saves the brushed dataframe. Also made output of `brushedPoints` as `reactive` so we can use it multiple times in the code.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", brush = "plot_brush"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info"),
  actionButton("save", "Save")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
  })
  
  data <- reactive({
    brushedPoints(mtcars, input$plot_brush, xvar = "wt", yvar = "mpg")
    })
  
  output$info <- renderPrint({data()})
  
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    write.csv(data(), 'brushed_data.csv', row.names = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```